# Is there an adjective that means "hard to get out from"?

Tags: word-request

Is there an adjective that means "hard to get out from"? Like an adjective that means "labyrinth-like" or more generally "hard to get out or off from". For example:

> Theses vines are ____.
>
> This huge old mansion is ____.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very literally, you could use "[labyrinthine](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/labyrinthine)". This could work for "This huge mansion is labyrinthine", but it would be awkward to say "These vines are labyrinthine".

The vines could be "[inescapable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inescapable)". If you are not yet in the vines, you could say they are "[impenetrable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impenetrable)" or "[impassable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impassable)" meaning you can't get into them.